# Como devem ser tratadas as questões do tipo "Quero isso, como faço?"

Tags: suporte

Saudações pessoal.

Sei que o título pode ser confuso, mas na verdade é que já deparei-me com questões onde o membro pede apresenta um problema e depois solicita aos outro uma solução e .(ponto)

Não se trata de pedir ajuda, mas de pedir a solução prontinha pra fazer o copy e paste.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como se deve dar tratamento a essas situações, ou já existe algum regulamento para isso.

Obrigado.

Comment: É mesmo duplicata. Para registrar aqui mesmo outras discussões relacionadas: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157/esclarecer-ou-fazer-o-trabalho-pelos-outros, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1137/3117, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-no-estilo-como-fazer-x

Comment: Vendo a sua pergunta eu leio "Quero tratar perguntas do tipo 'quero isso, como faço', como faço?" ;)