# O que fazer quando notar que a sua pergunta já foi feita/respondida? Se for uma duplicação?

Tags: suporte, perguntas-duplicadas

Acredito que o título da questão é muito descritivo:

O que fazer quando notar que a sua pergunta já foi feita/respondida? Se for uma duplicação?

Isso aconteceu com uma questão que coloquei mesmo aqui, no meta StackOverflow, e não sei como/o que fazer sobre o assunto. Devo remover? Marcar como respondida? Ou existe já alguma opção pré-definida para questões do gênero.

A pergunta em questão foi essa: [Como devem ser tratadas as questões do tipo “Quero isso, como faço?”](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1978/3117)

Comment: Se a pergunta foi fechada como duplicata, e se ficares satisfeito com as respostas da duplicata, não faças nada. A pergunta ficará bloqueada a respostas e será mais uma ajuda a quem estiver a pesquisar sobre o assunto para encontrar uma resposta.

Comment: Você percebeu por conta própria, antes de qualquer pessoa, que sua pergunta é uma duplicata, ou alguém fechou sua pergunta como duplicata?

Comment: Alguém o fez @Math. Agora fiquei pensando se seria possível redirecionar alguem automaticamente para a pergunta original (a que faz a minha ser considerada duplicata), ao invés de abrir a minha e depois ter de ir até a original.

Comment: Coloque um link para ela, para analisarmos o caso. Pode ajudar.

Answer (score 5):

Não faça nada, o que tinha que ser feito já foi feito.

As perguntas duplicadas não chegam a ser algo maléfico ao site, em muitas ocasiões elas podem ajudar pessoas a encontrar a resposta que precisam sem ter que buscar pelas exatas palavras que foram usadas na pergunta original, já que podem existir várias perguntas "iguais" entretanto usando palavras diferentes. O que não faria sentido é responder cada uma delas, por isso apenas a marcação de duplicata já é o suficiente.

Se for o caso de você mesmo descobrir que você fez uma pergunta duplicada, antes das outras pessoas perceberem isso, você pode sinalizá-la para atenção da moderação para que a pergunta possa ser fechada como duplicata. Só não faça isso de forma artificial, criando várias perguntas que já têm resposta e sinalizando como duplicatas, apenas para ampliar o leque de possíveis palavras que direcionam para um determinado assunto.

Sendo do jeito que aconteceu, você não fez nada de errado e tudo já está certo do jeito que está agora.